# Running squish test on slave (unix) machine using jenkins from master (windows)

Tags: jenkins, squish

I am trying to run squish test on slave machine using Jenkins from master machine.
While running build job from my master machine I am getting following errors:-

> Exception: com.froglogic.squish.SquishException: com.froglogic.squish.execute.TestCaseNotFoundException: Could not find tst_/home/admin/Desktop/Squish_setup/squish-6.0.1-qt47x-linux64/examples/qt/addressbook/suite_py/tst_general/test.py in suite /home/admin/Desktop/Squish_setup/squish-6.0.1-qt47x-linux64/examples/qt/addressbook/suite_py

(tried with and without tst_ prefix)

Also in the same console output under squish configuration in slave its showing the ip address of my Jenkins master machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't use the squish jenkins integration.

The issue you are having is with the use of absolute path. The squishrunner will look for the testcase name within the suite directory.

Secondly, the testcase should point to the folder, and not the .py file inside.

In this case it is looking for a folder:

```
tst_/home/admin/Desktop/Squish_setup/squish-6.0.1-qt47x-linux64/examples/qt/addressbook/suite_py/tst_general/test.py
```

Inside the folder:

```
/home/admin/Desktop/Squish_setup/squish-6.0.1-qt47x-linux64/examples/qt/addressbook/suite_py
```

This isn't going to work.

As I mentioned, I don't use jenkins, so I shall outline the cmdline that you would use, and I hope that can help you solve your problem?

```
squishrunner --testsuite \
/home/admin/Desktop/Squish_setup/squish-6.0.1-qt47x-linux64/examples/qt/addressbook/suite_py \
--testcase tst_general
```

You also seem to have a second problem, where it is showing the wrong IP address. That seems an issue unique to the jenkins integration, I'm sorry I can't shed any light on that. Unless that in the squishserver settings or something like that?

Comment: even after providing the path till folder getting this error :  >>  Exception: com.froglogic.squish.SquishException: com.froglogic.squish.execute.TestCaseNotFoundException: Could not find tst_/home/admin/Desktop/Squish_setup/squish-6.0.1-qt47x-linux64/examples/qt/addressbook/suite_js/tst_general in suite /home/admin/Desktop/Squish_setup/squish-6.0.1-qt47x-linux64/examples/qt/addressbook/suite_js (tried with and without tst_ prefix)